# Are there any penalties for using infinite ammo?

Tags: resident-evil-6

When you select a campaign, you also get to select some game mode settings (the bit with network play options). One of the options here is to enable infinite ammo - which is available in offline and online modes.

What does this mean? Can you use infinite ammo any time, or does this mean you can use an "infinite ammo" unlock reward once you have it? And more importantly, are there any disadvantages to enabling this mode? (e.g. prevents trophies, prevent completion progress)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option at the game setup is just there to allow you to choose whether or not to enable it for those players (i.e., in co-op) that have already bought it.

You will need to complete all 4 campaigns at least once to unlock the ability to purchase infinite ammo for your weapons. You will have to buy infinite ammo for each weapon separately.

The costs for each weapon are as follows:

**Handgun:** 79,000 skill points

**Shotgun:** 89,000 skill points

**Magnum:** 99,000 skill points

**Sniper Rifle:** 79,000 skill points

**Machine Pistol:** 89,000 skill points

**Assault Rifle:** 89,000 skill points

**Grenade Launcher:** 99,000 skill points

**Crossbow:** 79,000 skill points

Considering how difficult it is to unlock and obtain, I'm pretty sure it doesn't turn off achievements (RE5 did the same thing with infinite ammo). It's pretty balanced since infinite ammo has to take up one of your skills in your skill set, so you can only have infinite ammo for three types of weapons.

Comment: Its worth noting that by the time you unlock infinite ammo you have access to multiple skill slot setups, which can be switched during the game. So although you can only have 3 infinite ammo slots at any given time, you can easily switch to other skills throughout the same playthough

Answer (score 0):

You have to earn the infinite ammo first and it does not affect anything just like Resident Evil 5, it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually only use the infinite ammo in a difficulty that has been completed already. (I.e... If completed on professional you can't equip in No Hope).

Comment: that is new to me. didnt know that

Comment: I am pretty sure this isn't true. From what I remember you can unlock it before playing professional and then use it to complete professional for the first time. "No Hope" mode I think is a special case, where you are not allowed to use infinite ammo at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can not use infinite ammo on no hope, but you can on all the rest of the difficulties regardless if you have previously played it or not

Comment: Hi, Arqade is not a conventional forum. It is a hardcore Q&A site. If you have a question or follow-up query to this question, [please post it as a new question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to use infinite ammo on the first play-through of each campaign, and using it locks your ability to get achievements.

Comment: This is wrong, I can confirm that you can still get achievements/trophies when using infinite ammo